# Pattern name meaning: "Configurable Back-Ends"

Tags: design-patterns

What is the best name of the design pattern that describes a system where you can choose to CONFIGURE your system to be deployed using a back-end service from a list of compatible services? For example, software that can be CONFIGURED to use any number of different "brands" of SQL database: MySQL, PostGRES, Oracle, etc.
(Note: NOT a pattern that focuses on "hot swapping" backends at runtime.)

So far, in my research, I have come up with a handful of pattern names that do not seem to exactly describe this: Facade, PlugIn, Extensibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance it looked like one of [Decorator](http://www.dofactory.com/net/decorator-design-pattern) or [State](http://www.dofactory.com/net/state-design-pattern) design patterns. But this

> NOT a pattern that focuses on "hot swapping" backends at runtime

points that are not those two. So my next suggestion from Behavioral patterns will be the [Chain of responsibility](http://www.dofactory.com/net/chain-of-responsibility-design-pattern). Since it gives more than one object a chance to handle the request for the Persistence layer and

> use any number of different "brands" of SQL database: MySQL, PostGRES, Oracle, etc.

It also utilize avoiding the coupling of request's sender and its receiver. If the chaining of the receiving objects happens in .config files, then it fits this part too - pass the request along the chain until an object handles it (in this case maybe some environments Manager).

Comment: I agree that Chain_of_responsibility is an okay answer. Thanks. But it seems to focus on the 'chain" aspect , i.e., it focuses passing the request to another object in the chain more than the configurable-plugin aspect. I guess there just isn't a good answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

The nearest match would be strategy pattern but I think this is the wrong level of abstraction.